# Integrating Fsearch into dolphin file manager

Tags: kde, search, dolphin

Is there any way to integrate Fsearch prgoram into the dolphin file manager as a plugin so that it can view files within dolphin rather than a seperate window?
Best regards.

Comment: What is the source of `fsearch`? Please provide a link.

Comment: http://cboxdoerfer.github.io/fsearch/ mentions it's a GTK3 application built as a standalone program.

Comment: Is it impossible to integrate a Gtk application into a Qt one?

Comment: Your best bet is to contact the developer.

Comment: The developper specifically developed the program to be stand alonw